# Unable to manually trigger keydown event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, jquery-events

```
<form>
    <div id="part-inputs">
        <div class="part-input">
            <label>Part 1</label>
            <input type="number" class="start" name="s[0]" value="" placeholder="start time" tabindex="3">
            <input type="number" class="finish" name="f[0]" value="" placeholder="finish time" tabindex="4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name=submit>
</form>

<script>
    var nextPartNo = 2;
    var template = '<div class="part-input">' +
        '<label>Part <%= partNo %></label>' +
        '<input type="number" class="start" name="s[<%= partNo -1 %>]" value="" placeholder="start time" tabindex="<%= (partNo-1)*2+1 %>">' +
        '<input type="number" class="finish" name="f[<%= partNo -1 %>]" value="" placeholder="finish time" tabindex="<%= (partNo-1)*2+2 %>">' +
        '</div>';
    var compiledTemplate = _.template(template);

    // check for tab keydown at finish field
    $("#part-inputs").on('keydown', '.finish', function(event) {

        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

        if (keyCode == 9) { // tab key
            var $partInputTargeted = $(event.target.parentElement); // div#part-input
            if (!$partInputTargeted.is(':last-child')) {
                return;
            }
            $("#part-inputs").append(compiledTemplate({
                partNo: nextPartNo
            }));
            nextPartNo++;
        }
    });

    // check for enter key at both fields
    $("#part-inputs").on('keydown', ['.start', '.finish'], function(event) {

        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

        if (keyCode == 13) { // enter key
            console.log("here"); // this verifies we reach the block where we trigger jquery event 
            event.preventDefault();
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = e.keyCode = 9; // Create tab key event
            $(event.target).trigger(e);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Above is a snippet of the dynamic form, I am creating. There are multiple units of a `start field` and a `finish field`. Each unit is a `div#part-input`. All div#part-input  divs are children of `div#part-inputs`.

On tab event triggered at `finish field` of last `div#part-input`, a new `div#part-input` will be appended. I am compiling the template using underscore.js( This working as expected)

Now I want `enter key` at `any` of the fields(start or finish) to trigger `tab event` on the same . This where code is not doing anything.

Comment: dont use `[]`, just do `'keydown', '.start, .finish'`, info here https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Not working still. But earlier also  handler at enter key was called with [ ] as console.log statement verifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all looks like there is a typo in your submit button, missing the quotes around the name prop.

Try this, it should work for what you are looking for. It will trigger if the enter key is pressed while in a finished input. I took out our template adding to it's own function so you can call it in multiple places.

```js
function addTemplate() {
  var $partInputTargeted = $(event.target.parentElement); // div#part-input
  if (!$partInputTargeted.is(':last-child')) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('add new template');
}

$("#part-inputs .start, #part-inputs .finish").keydown(function (event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var index = $('input').index(this) + 1;
    $('input').eq(index).focus();
    
    if($(this).attr('class') === 'finish') {
      addTemplate();
    }
  }
});

// check for tab keydown at finish field
$("#part-inputs").on('keydown', '.finish', function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

  if (keyCode == 9) { // tab key
    addTemplate();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="part-inputs">
        <div class="part-input">
            <label>Part 1</label>
            <input type="number" class="start" name="s[0]" value="" placeholder="start time" tabindex="3">
            <input type="number" class="finish" name="f[0]" value="" placeholder="finish time" tabindex="4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you want to change focus on next input when user presses `enter` key. Why don't you directly set the focus with javascript? There is no need to fake keyboard events.

This snippet should help you:

```
$('input,select').keydown( function(e) { // Add event listener
  var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
  if(key == 13) { // If enter key
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputs = {YOUR INPUTS} // $('.YOUR-SEELCTOR-CLASS').find(':input:visible');
    var nextinput = 0;

    // Find next input
    if (inputs.index(this) < (inputs.length-1)) {
      nextinput = inputs.index(this)+1;
    }

    // Handle input focus
    if (inputs.length==1) {
      $(this).blur().focus();
    } else {
      inputs.eq(nextinput).focus();
    }
  }
});
```